# image in HTML shows a broken image

Tags: html, node.js, raspberry-pi

I am hosting a website with node.js on my raspberry pi.
I have a index.html file and want to show a picture.
The picture keep beeing a broken img symbol.
I have verified that the path is correct. And there is a copy of the picture on the raspberry.
Any help whould be appreciated.

index.html

```
<img src="./CV_Website/pageV.1/Profilbillede.jpg" width="810" height="760" alt="Andreas Steffensen" class="absolute top-0 right-0 w-1/4 h-auto">
```

[image: path & image file in directory]

I have tried testing on my pc and running it there on localhost with correct path to img and the problem persists.
I have also given permission with: `chmod 755 Profilbillede.jpg`
I have tried both relative and absolute paths.

Comment: `./CV_Website/pageV.1` seems pointing to a directory,. Where is `Profilbillede.jpg` in your image source?

Answer (score 0):

You say you tried both relative and absolute, but your link is a mix of the two.

The **absolute** should always **start with a /** and would look something like this :

```
<img src="/CV_Website/pageV.1/Profilbillede.jpg" >
```

And the relative, from the index.html we see, looks like this :

```
<img src="Profilbillede.jpg">
```

or if you want to keep the dot, which means 'current directory', like this :

```
<img src="./Profilbillede.jpg">
```

Depending on your browser you can, an should, inspect it to look for errors in the console.

Comment: Sorry for the typo that is what I have